# jQuery my submit button doesnt work

Tags: php, jquery, html

First of all, I am an absolute beginner, just started to code with jQuery mobile.

Works fine, but i created a html form with a normal submit button. When I click it, nothning happens... Maybe s.o. can help me through this?! Can't find my mistake....

This is my HTML-Form:

```
<form id='myform' action ='./update.php' method='POST'>";
    while($daten = mysql_fetch_array($re, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
        echo "<b>Titel:</b><br><input name=titelbox type=text value=" . $daten["Titel"] . "><br>";
echo "<b>Beschreibung:</b><br><input name=beschreibungbox type=text value=" . $daten["Beschreibung"] . "><br>";
echo "<b>Kunde:</b><br><input name=kundebox type=text value=" . $daten["Kunde"] . "><br>";
echo "<b>Baustelle:</b><br><input name=baustellebox type=text value=" . $daten["Baustelle"] . "><br>";
echo "<b>Ort:</b><br><input name=ortbox type=text value=" . $daten["Ort"] . "><br>";
echo "<b>Conainergr&ouml;sse:</b><br><input name=cont_grbox type=text value=" . $daten["Cont_Gr"] . "><br>";
echo "<b>Inhalt:</b><br><input name=inhaltbox type=text value=" . $daten["Inhalt"] . "><br>";
echo "<b>Bemerkung:</b><br><input name=bemerkungbox type=text value=" . $daten["Bemerkung"] . "><br>";
echo "<b>Zugewiesen:</b><br><input name=zugewiesenbox type=text value=" . $daten["Zugewiesen"] . "><br>";
echo "<b>Status:</b><br><input name=statusbox type=text value=" . $daten["Status"] . ">";
echo "<b>ID:</b><br><input name=idbox type=text value=" . $daten["ID"] . ">";

       }
}
echo"</div>";

mysql_close($link);
?>
<br>
<input type='submit' name='my_button' value='save'> 
<br>
</div><!-- /content -->
</body>
</html>
```

And this is whats between my < head > Tags:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/damke_mobile.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

----UPDATE----
When I comment out the .js Files, it works fine, but this is no solution....

Here is my whole page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Damke Mobile</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/damke_mobile.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile.css">
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="header">
<h1>Damke Portal - Details</h1>
<a href="mobile.php">Home</a>
</div><!-- /header -->
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
<?php
$ID = $_GET["ID"];
$server = "localhost";  
$datenbank = "****e";
$username = "****e";
$passwort = "*****1";
$link = mysql_connect($server, $username, $passwort);
if (!$link)            die(mysql_error());

$db = mysql_select_db($datenbank, $link);

if ($db)
    {
    $re = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Termine_Test where ID='$ID'", $link);
    echo"<div id='myform'><table width='90%'><form id='myform' action ='./update.php' method='POST'>";
    while($daten = mysql_fetch_array($re, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
    echo "<b>Titel:</b><br><input name=titelbox type=text value=" . $daten["Titel"] . "><br>";
echo "<b>Beschreibung:</b><br><input name=beschreibungbox type=text value=" . $daten["Beschreibung"] . "><br>";
echo "<b>Kunde:</b><br><input name=kundebox type=text value=" . $daten["Kunde"] . "><br>";
echo "<b>Baustelle:</b><br><input name=baustellebox type=text value=" . $daten["Baustelle"] . "><br>";
echo "<b>Ort:</b><br><input name=ortbox type=text value=" . $daten["Ort"] . "><br>";
echo "<b>Conainergr&ouml;sse:</b><br><input name=cont_grbox type=text value=" . $daten["Cont_Gr"] . "><br>";
echo "<b>Inhalt:</b><br><input name=inhaltbox type=text value=" . $daten["Inhalt"] . "><br>";
echo "<b>Bemerkung:</b><br><input name=bemerkungbox type=text value=" . $daten["Bemerkung"] . "><br>";
echo "<b>Zugewiesen:</b><br><input name=zugewiesenbox type=text value=" . $daten["Zugewiesen"] . "><br>";
echo "<b>Status:</b><br><input name=statusbox type=text value=" . $daten["Status"] . ">";
echo "<b>ID:</b><br><input name=idbox type=text value=" . $daten["ID"] . ">";

       }
}
echo"</div>";

mysql_close($link);
?>
<br>
<input type='submit' name='my_button' value='save'> 
</form>
<br>
</div><!-- /content -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: maybe because you didnt close your form tag

Comment: Your form tag will not work like this, you are inside a PHP code and not outside,  Can we see the first part of the page?  I'd like to see where "<?php"  is.

Comment: i suggest you refine your code more nicely. hardly to read.

Comment: added my whole code above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at your code and your division, your division are not closed properly:

Here's what's in your code at this time:

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <div id='myform'>
        <table width='90%'>
            <form id='myform' action ='./update.php' method='POST'>

    </div>
    <input type='submit' name='my_button' value='save'> 
            </form>
</div><!-- /content -->
```

- Your div #myform is being closed too early
- Your table is not being closed
- Your submit button and /form are outside of your #myform div

On a side note, you should reconsider this line:

```
$re = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Termine_Test where ID='$ID'", $link);
```

That's open for SQL Injection, your $ID is coming directly from $_GET

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think that things will be better if you add closing form tag somewhere

Comment: thank you, but this does not affect anything... Just added.. Nothing.

Comment: I'm sorry if this question disgust you but... I supposse you added </form> AFTER your button, isn't it?
It's a little weird because jquery (without any order) doesn't blocks form submission